# Split post or page content in two or more columns

Tags: php, posts, pages, twitter-bootstrap

I'm not using a pagebuilder, this because I like to offer to any client a different layout for the contents. I have the necessity to split the contant of a page or post in two or more columns, I'm using bootstrap 4 and I want to create some layouts without the necessity to hardcode the columns or put the div inside the post content directly. Is this possible, how I can make it?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Block Editor, use Core's column blocks.

If you're using the Classic Editor, make shortcodes for Bootstrap's rows and columns. When you enter content, you can then just enter

```
[row]
[column large="6"]First column content[/column]
[column large="6"]Second column content[/column]
[/row]
```

(You may find prebuilt shortcodes out in the wild since this is a common scenario. Or you may want to create your own as only you know which of the column widths you're likely to need.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm using the old editor of wordpress. I Have a custom plugin that can add bootsrrap grid layout to the post content, but I'm not using it for this project, I want to apply a solution that is coded and that will work with any theme, I don't want to put shortcodes or similar inside the content.

Comment: As long as you include the Bootstrap CSS in the same plugin as the shortcodes, it will work with any theme. I'm not sure what other form of layouts you're envisioning.

Comment: The solution will work only if the gutemberg editor is active, I'm using only the classic editor, the rows provided by gutemberg will not be the same of botstrap

Comment: Shortcodes work in either editor and you can have them provide the Bootstrap-specific classes etc.